Can we be alive in spinning Black Holes?
I was studying about black holes and I get to know that we can be alive in black holes if the black hole is spinning. I didn't understand the reason. Can anyone explain.
I mean to ask that if is it possible to stay alive after crossing the event horizon of a spinning blackhole?

This question is similar to: Is a stable orbit possible inside the ergosphere of a Kerr (spinning) black hole?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is different in my view: it seems to me that the OP is asking whether or not it is possible to avoid the singularity after passing the internal horizon.

is it still closed yet ?

This question is similar to: Are stable orbits within the event horizon of a black hole possible?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ShivanshMaheshwari I did find a duplicate. Have a look at my answer to the question Are stable orbits within the event horizon of a black hole possible?

@JohnRennie thanks
